# PHP json_encode trunk string when using international character like é

Tags: php, json

This simple code show you the problem:

```
class MyObject
{
    var $publicString = "This is a weird character : é and it will trunk this sentence";
}
$myObject = new MyObject();
var_dump(json_encode($myObject));
```

The var_dump output is :

```
 string(47) "{"publicString":"This is a weird character : "}"
```

Why?

Comment: What encoding is your PHP file in?

Comment: it depends what encoding you are using in your editor. when i paste this code in vi and run it from the terminal, it doesn't break the json string.

Comment: The code worked fine for me, something else must be causing the problem. I'm on PHP 5.2, OS X leopard.

Comment: @rubayeet that is because you are encoding your PHP file in UTF-8

Comment: It was Ansi :S Sorry, haven't see that NotePad++ created this type of encoding.

Comment: Any idea why on my Linux box any sentence are automatically NULL. The charset of the file is UTF-8. All work fine on Windows. Linux : object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["publicString"]=> NULL }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_encode()` expects UTF-8 data.

I assume your file is ISO-8859-1 encoded. ISO-8859-1 `é` is an invalid character in UTF-8.

A workaround would be storing the file as UTF-8, or doing an `iconv()`:

```
$myObject->publicString = 
     iconv("iso-8859-1", "utf-8//IGNORE", $myObject->publicString);

var_dump(json_encode($myObject));
```

Comment: Alright, I changed the default encoding to UTF8 and it works. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Pekka, so simple... sorry

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode()` only works with UTF-8 char set. Here's a [link to an example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#102452) on how to deal with this issue.